# Data is not Rendering to the Screen in React Project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a react application that I am trying to render some basic JSON to the screen. I will place a small snippet of the JSON object below. I am trying to represent the data in the researchPage. I will be placing the entire component class below. Please let me know if I can provide any further information to clarify.

db.json - This is the JSON file that I am trying to pull data from.

```
{

    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "issflightplan",
            "_type": "issflightplan",
            "_key": "IDP-ISSFLIGHTPLAN-0000000000000447",
            "_version": 1,
            "_score": null,
            "ContentType": {
                "__deferred": {
                    "uri": "https://bi.sp.iss.nasa.gov/Sites/FP/_api/Web/Lists(guid'a9421c5b-186a-4b14-b7b2-4b88ee8fab95')/Items(252)/ContentType"
                }
```

researchPage - This is the component page that I am trying to render the JSON data too. I have looked at the console and do not seem to be getting any errors. The page is showing, and the H1 Record MetaData is also rendering to the screen, however, there is no H3 or Paragraph below it.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import data from "../../data/db.json";


console.log(data);
class ResearchPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isLoading: false,
            error: null,
            dataSet: [],
            data: [],
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true });
        fetch(data)
            .then((res) => {
                debugger;
                if (res.ok) {
                    return res.json();
                } else {
                    throw Error("Error Fetching Data");
                }
            })
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
                this.setState({ data: data, isLoading: false });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log((error) => this.setState({ error }));
            });
    }
    render() {

        const { error, isLoading, data } = this.state;
        const dataItems =  data.map((dataSet) => (
            <div key={dataSet.id}>
                <h3>{dataSet._index}</h3>
                <p>{dataSet.uri}</p>
            </div>
        ));
        if (error) {
            return <p style={{ color: "red" }}>{error.message}</p>;
        }
        if (!isLoading) {
            return <p>Loading Data...</p>;
        } else
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>Record MetaData</h1>
                        {dataItems}
                </div>
            );
    }
}
export default ResearchPage;
```

Comment: Can you add a debugger; under fetch(data)
            .then((res) => { and see if it ever gets called? Also change componentwillmount to componentdidmount event.

Comment: Does the data show in your console log?

Comment: I dont see the object in the console at all.

Comment: I added the debugger but dont seem to see the data being called?

Comment: You have !isLoading inverted and I successfully ran your module with test data so, it's for sure in your DidMount => fetch.

Comment: @Nicholas_Jones any Idea what it might be in the DidMount? I can not seem to find it?

Comment: @Nicholas_Jones did you use the exact same code block against test data, or did you change it in any way?

Comment: When I made that comment i simply wrote test data to simulate your json file but, I believe my new answer should fix you problem. I'll add how to do this troubleshooting step to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

I got it working.

The problem I was facing was when trying to display the data was that the data in the render method wasn't initialized but, if you do the mapping inside the didmount  and also it looks like your trying to access the list so you need to specify that.

```
const hits = data.hits.map((dataSet) => (
      <div key={dataSet.id}>
         <h3>{dataSet._index}</h3>
         <p>{dataSet.uri}</p>
       </div>
 ));

 this.setState({ data: hits, isLoading: false });


render() {
    const { error, isLoading, data } = this.state;
    if (error) {
        return <p style={{ color: "red" }}>{error.message}</p>;
    }
    if (isLoading) {
        return <p>Loading Data...</p>;
    } else {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Record MetaData</h1>
                {data}
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

Oh also, I put the db.json in the public directory and accessed it as follows because I was getting module not found.

```
fetch("db.json", {
        headers: { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }})
.then (...)
```

How to troubleshooting

To feed some example test data to see if it's and IO issue you can convert the json object manually into a javascript object like so,

```
this.setState({ data: [
    { _index: 'ia', uri: 'ub' },
    { _index: 'ib', uri: 'ub' },
], isLoading: false });
```

More Explanation

Issues you faced

Component Lifecycle - The ComponentDidMount will fire after or at the same time that render fires. This raised a concurrency issue where the data you were trying to map was not use was not yet available. By doing the map inside the DidMount ensures that it's performed only once the data is ready. In the meantime the {data} in the render will be null and nothing will be displayed. If you wanted to test this you could put a sleep/block inside your didmount and see that the data won't display until the block is complete.

Correctly navigating the json object - Using data.map instead of data.hits.map was targeting the entire json object and not the specific list "hits" that actually needed to be accessed (data.hits). Next the .map function iterates through that list providing 'dataSet' on each iteration which allow the use that value.

Potential - I don't normally get data from a json file but, instead from web API's so, I have little experience but, normally to access the file you need a special library or have to put the file inside your public folder which is available throughout the project. You can test this by doing http://localhost:3000/db.json

Comment: Nicholas, this doesnt seem to fix the issue. That solution does not enable me to pass the variable dataItems to the return with record metadata

Comment: Ok I think I see another problem. Give me a second and I'll update the solution

Comment: That fixed it. I am honestly not sure why, but that fixed it. I wish I could understand the reason for this a little better, if your willing to offer a bit of an explanation?

Comment: Yes, I'll try to elaborate further.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!isLoading) {
            return <p>Loading Data...</p>;
```

This is backwards. It should be:

```
if (isLoading) {
            return <p>Loading Data...</p>;
```

Comment: The only thing that renders to the screen after changing this is loading data...